# How to optimize Javascript to make it shorter

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization

I'm new to coding, and I'm looking to optimize this JavaScript code ?
What is your recommendation? Should i use a variable pour the hour number?
How could i try to not repeat the same else if and make it shorter?

```js
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
            if (0 == currentTime) {
                document.body.className = "sky-gradient-00";
            }
            else if (1 == currentTime) {
                document.body.className = "sky-gradient-01";
            }
            ...
            else if (22 == currentTime) {
                document.body.className = "sky-gradient-22";
            }
            else if (23 == currentTime) {
                document.body.className = "sky-gradient-23";
            }
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sky-gradient-00,
.sky-gradient-24 {
  background: #00000c;
}

.sky-gradient-01 {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #020111 85%, #191621 100%);
}

.sky-gradient-22 {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #090401 50%, #4B1D06 100%);
}

.sky-gradient-23 {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00000c 80%, #150800 100%);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body class="">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like you said use a variable. Just use the hours and pad it when it is less than 10.

```
if(currentTime < 10) currentTime = "0" + currentTime;
document.body.className = "sky-gradient-" + currentTime;
```

Comment: Can you tell me why i should use "if (currentTime < 10)" ?

Comment: @Wally - That part is to always have the value with two digits... (add the zero to the left)

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
var cls = "sky-gradient-";

if (currentTime < 10) {
   cls = cls + "0" + currentTime;
} else {
   cls += currentTime ;
}
document.body.className = cls;
```